# Why is a csrf token needed when a session cookie is used?

Tags: security, cookies, csrf

Say I login through an opendID connect provider and am redirected to my callback `www.mysite.com/auth/callback`. I then create an httponly cookie, which contains an id referencing to my received tokens, that is passed to the browser at `wwww.mysite.com/`. How would another site submit a request that contains that same session cookie? Does the browser not pass only the cookies of the requesting domain. So if `www.evil.com` tries to make a request to `www.mysite.com/api/endpoint`, won't the session cookie not be passed, making the forged request invalid?

Am I missing something basic here??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When web browsers send a request to a different domain, they're nice enough to first check if they already have cookies for that domain, and if they do, then they send them along with the request. So, if you're on a web application trying to send a request to your app, it'll send that request along with your cookies. The idea behind the anti-forgery token is that even when the web browser sends all that information, if the token doesn't match with the one that you create on a legit request submitted from your application, it'll fail.

If you don't want your cookies being sent via cross-site requests, you can use the `samesite` flag for your cookies. Here you can decide between Strict and Lax mode. In Strict mode, you'll never send your site cookies via cross-site requests, so you don't need to care about session cookies being sent. The problem here is that if you're redirected from a different site, from example, if you're here, and try to go to facebook (if facebook used strict mode), your cookies will not be sent, and you'll need to authenticate again (it can be an annoying or a good feature, depending of your application and your user-base).
The Lax mode is pretty similar, but in this mode, you'll only send your cookies via safe HTTP verbs (GET, HEAD, OPTIONS and TRACE), so you still get your protection against POST/PUT XSRF attacks, and you don't have an annoying behaviour for the GET requests. It's up to you to decide which one will be the better option for your app.

More info about XSRF and samesite cookies: http://arnoldcer.com/2017/03/14/cross-site-request-forgery-what-it-is-how-to-exploit-it-and-how-to-defend-against-it/

Comment: I envisioned that the if the browser was at url `evil.com`, it would use that as the request domain, regardless of what request was made on that page. This is incorrect. The browser will add cookies according to the domain of the respective request. The samesite flag is an interesting alternative to the need for a csrf token.